Custom expectations: Reuse existing `testthat` functions
I came up with these lines to test if an R list contains a certain element at a given index (supplied by purrr::pluck syntax):
library(testthat)

expect_list_contains <- function(object, val, ...) {
  # 1. Capture object and label
  act <- quasi_label(rlang::enquo(object), arg = "object")
  # 2. Call expect()
  act$is_list <- rlang::is_list(object)
  act$does_exist <- purrr::pluck_exists(object, ...)
  act$actual_value <- purrr::pluck(object, ...)
  expect(
    isTRUE(act$is_list),
    sprintf("%s not a list.", act$lab)
  )
  expect(
    isTRUE(act$does_exist),
    sprintf("no element in %s at the given index.", act$lab)
  )
  msg <- paste(
    "element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.\n",
    "  `actual`: %s",
    "`expected`: %s",
    sep = "\n"
  )
  expect(
    isTRUE(identical(act$actual_value, val)),
    sprintf(msg,
            deparse(act$actual_value),
            deparse(val)
    )
  )

  # 3. Invisibly return the value
  invisible(act$val)
}

My goal is to mimic existing expectations and provide a concise description of why the expectation failed (if so).
I have the feeling that I could piggyback on existing testthat code much more.
How could I refactor my code such that it resembles original testthat expectations, especially concerning the returned expectation failure messages (maybe by using existing expectation as working-horses of my function)?

I didn't downvote. But it's not immediately clear how to use the OP code -- it is generic and needs comments or at least examples.

documentation comments
In any language I expect a public function I'm calling
to have some sort of a man page, describing inputs and outputs.
expect_list_contains <- function(object, val, ...) {

The function name is very helpful, thank you.
It suggests we're evaluating a boolean function
whose expectation will blow up if "contains" is false, good.
But we have only this function signature to go on,
with no Rdocumentation comments surrounding it.
And there is dissonance between list and object.
Maybe there is some cultural thing going on that I'm unaware of,
like conventionally certain parameters should be named object?
Naming it a list seems reasonable, as an aid to the reader.
And certainly once rlang::is_list() has verified that,
we could assign list <- object.
Identifiers change how we think about the code -- choose good ones!
objects are nouns
"Act" can have a bunch of meanings.
  act <- ...

But here I get the sense it's an abbreviation for "actor"?
A comment that helps with my mental pronunciation would be useful.
As written, I tend to keep viewing it as a
verb,
yet this struct has no callable methods.
evaluate for side effects
It's unclear why naming and storing intermediate results is helpful here.
  act$is_list <- rlang::is_list(object)
  ...
  expect(
    isTRUE(act$is_list),

You're asking a maintenance engineer to worry about how is_list
and several other variables will interact with later code.
Which turns out (currently) to be "empty set".
Simpler to just ask whether isTRUE(rlang::is_list(object)).
Similarly for does_exist and actual_value.
Since I maintain software, I always have my paranoid hat on.
Things could go south, and they often do.
In between the is_list assignment and its expectation,
we call pluck_exists(), for which I need to consult the
documentation to find that it "never" fails.
Similarly for the pluck() call.
Prefer to blow up at once upon finding a non-list,
rather than tempting fate with several intermediate calls.
informative diagnostic
  msg <- paste(
    "element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.\n",

I wonder, could we easily (and robustly) find what the index was?
I don't know the answer offhand.
I'm just saying that the first question in the mind of a maintenance
engineer staring at a bug report will be, "now what was that given index?"
This same concern is a big part of why we use quasi_label() and !!.
local variable
  act$actual_value <- purrr::pluck(object, ...)
  ...
  expect(
    isTRUE(identical(act$actual_value, val)),

I like the identical() call, I find it admirably clear.
Maybe a local variable would suffice, rather than tacking on another field
onto act?
In particular, the
documentation
explains we get val and lab back.
Jamming actual_value in there feels like we have a new kind of object
which isn't documented and which would not be fair game for passing
into another helper function.

tl;dr: Better docs, please. And a better diagnostic.

Very insightful thank you. I must admit I simply followed (blindly) the docs on custom expectations, but I was wondering too why they placed the intermediate results in act (also this naming choice wasn't mine to start with). As for the indices I would love to stringify them in a way, but given that there are many ways of indexing with pluck (think accessor functions) it seems to be not easily generalizable. As for the docs, full ack. Thanks for the advise, appreciated.

Why so complicated?
I'm not really familiar with the testthat conventions. All the quasiquotation looks overly complicated for checking whether an item exists in a list at a given index. My instinct would just be to start with something like:
check_item_at_index <- function(lst, idx, val) {
    identical(lst[[idx]], val)
}

And then work from there to handle edge cases. I imagine that there are good reasons that this will not work for you. I think it would have been helpful to post some test cases to get a sense of the requirements.
Surprising results: stricter type checks than equality
Some results are a bit surprising to me. Let's define a list with some basic values and some edge cases:
l <- list(
    a = "a", b = "b", c = c("c1", "c2"), d = 4, e = 5L,
    f = list(f1 = "f1"), na = NA, na_int = NA_integer_, null = NULL
)

As you know but for the benefit of others, in R, integers (specified by appending L) and numeric values are equal. For example:
4L==4
# [1] TRUE

But your function doesn't think they are:
expect_list_contains(l, 4L, 4)
# Error: element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`: 4
# `expected`: 4L

This is because you're using identical() rather than == which is a stricter check. The same applies to NA which is type checked. So these both do not pass:
expect_list_contains(l, NA_real_, 7)
expect_list_contains(l, NA, 8)

Similarly with environments, this might be the desired result, but I don't think the message is hugely helpful:
expect_list_contains(
    list(e1 = list2env(list(a = 1))),
    list2env(list(a = 1)),
    1
)
# Error: element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`: <environment>
# `expected`: <environment>

Similar caveats will apply to complex objects. For example, an igraph:
expect_list_contains(
    list(igraph::make_ring(0)),
    igraph::make_ring(0),
    1
)
# Error: element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`: structure(list(0, FALSE, numeric(0), numeric(0), NULL, NULL,
# `expected`: structure(list(0, FALSE, numeric(0), numeric(0), NULL, NULL,
# element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`:     NULL, NULL, list(c(1, 0, 1), list(name = "Ring graph", mutual = FALSE,
# `expected`:     NULL, NULL, list(c(1, 0, 1), list(name = "Ring graph", mutual = FALSE,
# element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`:         circular = TRUE), structure(list(), names = character(0)),
# `expected`:         circular = TRUE), structure(list(), names = character(0)),
# element (`actual`) at the given index not equal to `expected`.

#   `actual`:         structure(list(), names = character(0))), <environment>), class = "igraph")
# `expected`:         structure(list(), names = character(0))), <environment>), class = "igraph")

This is very verbose and not that instructive. I imagine this is OK and the function isn't meant to handle objects like this but it would be good to be clearer about that.
NULL values
This is arguably unfair because you shouldn't have NULL in a list, but R does let you, and this doesn't return what I would expect:
expect_list_contains(l, NULL, 9)
# Error: no element in `l` at the given index.

Minor comments
I don't think you need isTRUE in isTRUE(identical(act$actual_value, val)). The identical function can only return TRUE or FALSE.
Overall comments
The function did what I expected for most of the values in the list I came up with. Equality is a tricky issue, particularly in a language like R where you can assign attributes or even a class to any object, which often will not make much practical difference. I think the unexpected cases are fine if documented. There will be lots more examples where equality is case-dependent (e.g. another one I just thought of, a factor with the same values but different levels). I think that's fine as long as it's clear to the user of the function what type of objects they can expect to use it on and how strict the checks are.

Thank you very much for all the tips. The idea of the whole quasiquotation thing is that it should make labels a bit more informative and also shows the value of the slot which is different. It would be very nice to pinpoint the user to the exact index where there is a mismatch but his seems to be very tricky as well. It was a deliberate choice to use identical to be more strict (we are talking about unit testing). stringifying complicated objects is not trivial, hence I was hoping to piggyback more on existing code which does it already much better than my cheap deparse. +1 in any case

The more I think about it, the more I would like to find 2 solutions: a nicer string representation of the slot which is different and a way to point the tester to the index where the mismatch happens. The quasi_label is a good starting point as it deals with all the nastyness of lazy evaluation but I will look into some other tidyverse packages to see how the stringify complicated objects.

@thothal I think a bit more context would help me to understand how to best approach this. I'm guessing that rather than building a package with custom expect* functions, this test is for functions in a specific domain? I think in general identical() is a good choice (== is not implemented for many types). But for example ggplots are hard to test for equality. Similarly factors, S4/S7 objects, matrices/vectors. The use case will make it clear whether this matters and what equality means.
